# Linking source to .jars in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This framework distribution includes a `lib` folder (where all the binary .jars are) and a `src` one (where you can find the corresponding .javas for each .jar). So far I only have added `lib` to the Java project build path.

How would you copy `src` now? Just adding it or is there a way of somehow *link* it to `lib`? I don't have in mind what the gain would exactly consist of but I reckon that that would be somewhat better.

**Edit** - `src` is provided as a folder hierarchy, not source .jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not modifying the source, performance will be better if the source for each jar is in its own source jar.  It's usually also more convenient.  This is a convention at this point - especially if you can get the jars from a maven repository.  Each jar should be organized as you'd expect, with top level directory(s) "org", "com", etc.  In the build path, you can attach a source jar to each binary jar.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that the source folder does not include source .jars - only plain folders. How do I do the attach then? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to jar them yourself.  Sorry.  [Should be no big deal.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html).  If it's something from your own company that changes often, and there are several jars, you'll probably want to set up a script to do it - ant, .cmd, .sh, whatever.  If it's open-source from somewhere else, you may want to look for the [here](http://mvnrepository.com/).

Comment: It would probably work to make one big source jar and attach it to all of the binary jars, if that helps.  Not sure, though.

Comment: I noticed that some libraries are provided as a bundle .jar so yeah, it's a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but if you have added jars to your build path, you can right click on individual jars in the Project Explorer and select Properties.  In the resulting pop-up is a Java Source Attachment tab, which has options for linking source files depending on where they're located.

The main advantage to this that I'm aware of is when you're debugging code that makes use of the jars.  If you have source attached, you can step through the code, including comments (which are not available if you use a de-compiling tool to step through classes for which you don't have source).

Comment: That's a good starting point! The only thing now is - doing this for every single .jar would be bit of a pain. There seems to be no fix available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803740/how-to-add-source-files-of-library-jars