# Linking sourcefiles to compiled files within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javac

I'm trying to build a jar from an existing project. Since I want to be able to lookup the sourcecode within Eclipse (debugging etc.), I need to link the source files. I compiled the sources with this expression:

```
    javac -d classes/ -s src/ -verbose -g -sourcepath Framework/ src/DivaAPI.java src/DivaCallBase.java
```

Afterwards I run this commands:

```
    cd classes
    jar -cvmf manifest.txt Framework.jar package/name/*.class > nul
```

My directories look like this:

- root

  - src

    - *.java files*
  - classes

    - package/name/.class files
    - manifest.txt

Afterwards, the generated jar-file is copied to the lib ordner within my project, import it in the library tab (properties/Java Build Path/Library ) and almost everything works fine. Except the source code viewing of the imported library. I can't figure out how to link my existing sources in Eclipse. I know about the "attach source" button. But if I click it and select the correct source folder, Eclipse tells me that the folder doesn't contain any source files.

It seems to me that I do something wrong, but I just can't figure out, what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I needed to search just a little bit more. With the help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687150/linking-source-to-jars-in-eclipse) ( First answere and second comment of that answere, all by @Ed Staub ), I figured it out.

The easiest way is to generate a new jar, but this time with java files. Name it and copy it to the lib folder. Use the "attach source" button again and navigate to the lib folder and select the source.jar.

Now, everything should work the right way.